# Missing cygXau-6.dll error when starting a exe depending on cairo

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin, mingw, cairo

I've compiled the following code with gcc on cygwin:

```
#include <cairo.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        cairo_surface_t *surface =
            cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 240, 80);
        cairo_t *cr =
            cairo_create (surface);

        cairo_select_font_face (cr, "serif", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_BOLD);
        cairo_set_font_size (cr, 32.0);
        cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        cairo_move_to (cr, 10.0, 50.0);
        cairo_show_text (cr, "Hello, world");

        cairo_destroy (cr);
        cairo_surface_write_to_png (surface, "hello.png");
        cairo_surface_destroy (surface);
        return 0;
}
```

The code is from the official cairo homepage, so I assume it should run.

compiling with this command:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo.exe -I /usr/include/cairo/ -L /usr/lib -lcairo
```

It compiles without a problem, but trying to open the .exe (regularly in the windows file explorer) throws this error:

"The program could not be started, since cygXau-6.dll is missing on your PC. Reinstall the program, to fix the problem."

(roughly translated from german)

But that dll seems to be cygwin-specific and I'd like to not have my .exe depend on cygwin.

I'm new to C (coming from a webdev background) and the whole concept of linking is foreign to me, but I understand that I'll likely need to include the DLLs somewhere near the executable, and maybe link to it with the -I flag.

I don't even know if this is the right approach when building cross-platform C, but my first goal would be to simply get this snippet running under windows.

It does work when compiling with "regular" gcc and running it as kairo.o in cygwin - it produces the desired result, a png with "Hello, World".

The theory that I've compiled some sort of Hybrid seems to confirm itself - I've checked the exe with dependencywalker and got the following output.

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

So I guess I need to find out where I can get the mingw-binaries and header files for cairo and link to those. I just have no idea where to get them.

according to apt-cyg mingw-i686-cairo is installed - I linked to the files in the header file and it compiled as well, but now executing the .exe gives me another error: 
the application could not be started (0x000007b).

the following command was used to compile this time:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc kairo.c -o kairo.exe -I /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/cairo/ -L /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/ -lcairo
```

So I've done some more research and it seems I might still have some mixup between files compiled for 32 and 64 bits. Might have to do with the dlls

Comment: It seems you built an hybrid. Do you have `mingw64-i686-cairo` installed ?

Comment: according to apt-cyg mingw-i686-cairo is installed - I linked to the files in the header file and it compiled as well, but now executing the .exe gives me another error: the application could not be started (0x000007b).